# iOS use ID3Lib to edit ID3 tags from mp3 files in the NSDocsDir

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mp3, id3, nsdocumentdirectory

I am using [ID3Lib](https://github.com/rjyo/libid3-ios) example project to edit Title, Album and Artist ID3 tags on mp3 files and all is good until I come to adding an image (cover Art) if any one has any ideas how to finish off the below code that would be great:

```
- (void)demo {


nImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"amazing-grace.jpg"];//unused

NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"amazing-grace" ofType:@"jpg"];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"amazing-grace-10s" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"amazing-grace-10s.mp3"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path toPath:docPath error:nil];

// Read title tag
ID3_Tag tag;
tag.Link([path UTF8String]);

ID3_Frame *titleFrame = tag.Find(ID3FID_TITLE);
unicode_t const *value = titleFrame->GetField(ID3FN_TEXT)->GetRawUnicodeText();
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithCString:(char const *) value encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"The title before is %@", title);


// Write title tag
tag.Link([docPath UTF8String]);
tag.Strip(ID3FID_TITLE);
tag.Strip(ID3FID_ALBUM);
tag.Strip(ID3FID_LEADARTIST);
tag.Clear();

ID3_Frame frame;
frame.SetID(ID3FID_TITLE);
frame.GetField(ID3FN_TEXTENC)->Set(ID3TE_UNICODE);
NSString *newTitle = nTitle;
frame.GetField(ID3FN_TEXT)->Set((unicode_t *) [newTitle cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]);

ID3_Frame frame2;
frame2.SetID(ID3FID_ALBUM);
frame2.GetField(ID3FN_TEXTENC)->Set(ID3TE_UNICODE);
NSString *newAlbum = nAlbmum;
frame2.GetField(ID3FN_TEXT)->Set((unicode_t *) [newAlbum cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]);

ID3_Frame frame3;
frame3.SetID(ID3FID_LEADARTIST);
frame3.GetField(ID3FN_TEXTENC)->Set(ID3TE_UNICODE);
NSString *newArtist = nArtist;
frame3.GetField(ID3FN_TEXT)->Set((unicode_t *) [newArtist cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]);

//this is the image code 
ID3_Frame frame4;
frame4.SetID(ID3FID_PICTURE);
frame4.GetField(ID3FN_TEXTENC)->Set(ID3TE_UNICODE);// dont think this should be TEXTENC
NSString *newImage = imagePath;
frame4.GetField(ID3FN_DATA)->FromFile((const char *)[newImage cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]);//this line is also probably wrong


tag.AddFrame(frame);
tag.AddFrame(frame2);
tag.AddFrame(frame3);
tag.AddFrame(frame4);

tag.SetPadding(false);
tag.SetUnsync(false);
tag.Update(ID3TT_ID3V2);

NSLog(@"The title after is %@ The album after is %@ The artist after is %@ The artist after is %@", newTitle,newAlbum,newArtist,newImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use file path with UTF-8 encoding and will work fine:

```
frame.GetField(ID3FN_DATA)->FromFile((const char *)[newImage cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this code, From this source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/id3lib/+/8a58cac9f8db5ed55b02b3ac24156d628af923d1/examples/test_pic.cpp

```
frame.SetID(ID3FID_PICTURE);
frame.GetField(ID3FN_MIMETYPE)->Set("image/jpeg");
frame.GetField(ID3FN_PICTURETYPE)->Set(11);
frame.GetField(ID3FN_DESCRIPTION)->Set("B/W picture of Saint-Saëns");
//frame.GetField(ID3FN_DATA)->FromFile("composer.jpg");
frame.GetField(ID3FN_DATA)->FromFile((const char *)[newImage cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

tag.AddFrame(frame);
```

And! this work nice. :D

Comment: for cover artwork you should set as frame4.GetField(ID3FN_PICTURETYPE)->Set(ID3PT_COVERFRONT);