# Write metadata to mp3 local file

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, metadata

I´m reading metadata from mp3 file, by this way [iOS AVFoundation: How do I fetch artwork from an mp3 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030746/ios-avfoundation-how-do-i-fetch-artwork-from-an-mp3-file) and works perfectly.

when the file is mp3 and  doesn´t have artwork, or title, i'm getting NULL values.

I need, when the file haven't metadata like artwork or title, to write my own metadata in the mp3 file, put my own artwork and my own title.

How i can write metadata in mp3 local files on iOS7?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as no one answered.

I found the solution, I including this library in the project: https://github.com/rjyo/libid3-ios, which allows you to edit the ID3 tags of any mp3 file.

Some modifications I had to do to make it work properly with xCode5 and iOS7.

Instead - Step 4 (Quick Start (Xcode 4) repo instructions):

Add the following to Link Binary With Libraries list

- libiconv.2.4.0.dylib
- Libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
- libz.1.2.5.dylib
- libid3.a

Once you've successfully added the libid3-ios libraries in your project, read this question [iOS use ID3Lib to edit ID3 tags from mp3 files in the NSDocsDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299197/ios-use-id3lib-to-edit-id3-tags-from-mp3-files-in-the-nsdocsdir/23228152#23228152), for understand the libid3 API faster.

Remember you should use .mm extension instead of .m for objective-c containing c++ code.